How to use renderList in Agenda react-native-calendars?
I can get the renderItem to work fine, but it shows the '16 Tue' Date, I dont need that , and want to create a custom list with only the timeSlots, but I am unable to do so...
screenshot
I can do renderList={() => (some function that returns JsX)} , but that is static, I want to get only the data for the date I select [I want to get the time slots data available only for the date I select]

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
